# Why must a TogglzRule be declared public?

Tags: togglz

If i declare a TogglzRule in an Unit-Test it must be public, otherwise there will be thrown an exception: `java.lang.Exception: The @Rule 'togglzRule' must be public.`

I used to declare members private, why is this not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a JUnit restriction. It's required to make injection of the rule work without doing any "dirty tricks". From the javadocs of `@Rule`:

> Annotates fields that reference rules or methods that return a rule. A field must be public, not static, and a subtype of `org.junit.rules.TestRule` (preferred) or `org.junit.rules.MethodRule`.